# Setting learningRateMultiplier in CNTK from within Python

Tags: cntk

I am loading a pre-trained network and would like to change/set the "learningRateMultiplier" for various layers. I have done this before using Brainscript (link see below), but need to do this now from within Python. Is this supported? Or is there any other way in Python to set per-layer specific learning rates?

Brainscript:
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Parameters-And-Constants

To give some context: I would like to fine-tune all layers in Fast R-CNN training including the conv layers. However past experiments indicate that this requires smaller learning rates for the conv layers compared to the fc layers (perhaps due to the gradients from all ROIs being added up or otherwise combined).

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Unless a better alternative surfaces, I'd recommend creating two [learners](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.learners.html) with different learning rates and disjoint `parameters` arguments. You can provide a list with multiple learners to your model's [Trainer](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.train.html?highlight=trainer#module-cntk.train.trainer), which should coordinate their use during training.

Comment: Thanks for the help!